# Can't change font size

Tags: html, css

when I change the font size in ".box2" (inside the css file) I noticed that the font size in the browser remains the same without changing according to the code. Why?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

body p {
  padding: 30px;
  /*    font-family: Courier;*/
  text-align: justify;
}

.box2 {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: violet;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 30;
}

.box1:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Fixed Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box1">
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A typo?  Did you mean `font-size: 30px;` ?

Comment: You can find out how to change the `font-size` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). As David mentions, you are missing something after 30, so take a look what you want or need.

Comment: As @David said your are not using any unit like `px`, `rem` `rm` etc just writing 30 means nothing .

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up the absolute-size or relative-size like `px, em, rem, cm,` etc

Try the example below:

```
.box2 {
        margin: 30px;
        background-color: yellow;
        color: violet;
        font-family: Courier;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incomplete, as you have not mentioned any unit in the font-size property.
Instead of writing, font-size: 30, you should write font-size: 30px.